# PublishedItemsFilterData's IncludeTemplates property is ignored?

Tags: web8, core-service

I have the following code segment:

```
PublishedItemsFilterData publishedItemsFilterData = new PublishedItemsFilterData()
{
    BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended,
    IncludeTemplates = true
};
XElement publishInfoDataXElement = client.GetSystemWideListXml(publishedItemsFilterData);
```

which results in the following xml:

```
<tcm:ListPublishedItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:ext="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/R5/Extension">
    ...
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:8-122" Title="Programming 1"></tcm:Item>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:10-122" Title="Programming 1"></tcm:Item>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:11-122" Title="Programming 1"></tcm:Item>
    ...
</tcm:ListPublishedItems>
```

As you can see, see the `IncludeTemplates` is ignored and no extra column is included, however, when I query the `Publish States` table with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP (1000)
      [REFERENCE_ID]
      ,[ITEM_TYPE]
      ,[PUBLICATION_ID]
      ,[STATE]
      ,[TEMPLATE_REFERENCE_ID]
      ,[TEMPLATE_ITEM_TYPE]
FROM [dbo].[PUBLISH_STATES] WHERE REFERENCE_ID = 122
```

I get the following:

[image: Query Result]

which clearly has the template column set (is not null). What am I doing wrong, why doesn't the template column get included in the Core Service response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood the purpose of the `IncludeTemplates` property of the `PublishedItemsFilterData` filter.

This tells the `GetSystemWideListXml` whether to include Component Templates (as part of a published Dynamic Component Presentation) in the list, which otherwise would only include Pages, Components, Categories, and Target Groups.

Furthermore the API documentation also specifies the following remark on the `PublishedItemsFilterData` class:

> List column Filter Default and Extended have no impact.

So it seems the list you are getting returned, indeed can only contain ID and title.